# Android: simulate long running time

Tags: android

I guess everybody experienced his app work great when you try it for a quick 30 minutes. But when an app sits in the background of the device for a day or so, you get your `NullPointerExceptions` and things don't work as expected because the `Garbage Collector` stole your stuff.
Is there any way to simulate an app running for a long time in the background?

Comment: What `NullPointerException`s are you getting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Settings -> Developer options -> Background process limit -> At most 1 process.

Don't forget to set it back when you're done having fun. Cheers.

Comment: There is no such thing as being dormant. If by dormant, you mean still in RAM, paused state, then it doesn't make any sense to test it after 30 mins, if it still is in RAM. Everything will be the same. GC will only affect objects that are no longer being referenced. So GC alone won't affect anything. What *will* however affect the application lifecycle is recreation of activities or fragments, which can be tested by using the above method.

Comment: Again, the GC will collect un-referenced objects even while the activity is in the foreground, I didn't doubt that at all. It *won't* however collect referenced objects at all, in either state. As the objects you're using in the activity are being hosted *inside* that activity, then the reference checks out. If you know this fact to be the opposite, please provide references. However, I haven't encountered at all what you are describing.

Comment: From Dev SDK: "When your activity is stopped, the Activity object is kept resident in memory and is recalled when the activity resumes. You don’t need to re-initialize components that were created during any of the callback methods leading up to the Resumed state. " So, unless you're doing something out of the ordinary (where of course you need to make sure everything is fine), nothing is going to be collected by the GC; because, well, those objects aren't *garbage*. Yet. So the only thing you need to check is if the activity was destroyed. Which, again, you can do so by using the method above

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to wait any specific amount of time. You just have to do something that eats memory. This could be a special app you create for the task, but you don't really need to.

In my experience, most games seem to work. Games with a lot of graphics tend to work best, since they're using up a lot of memory for textures, etc. Angry Birds or Candy Crush will work also, even though there aren't advanced graphics or heavy processing(probably for the same reason they chew through the battery). Normally, after playing just a level or so, you can return to your Activity and see what got lost.

Optimally, you'll be using smart ways to persist/initialize your data, so this shouldn't be that much of a problem, but occasionally you(or a user) run into something unexpected, and this can help you track it down.